# How can i delete token generated by jwt? Is there a way to delete the token upon logout.

Tags: node.js

This is the code upon login. and i want to delete the toke upon logout

```
function(err, user) {
          if (user) {
            var token = jwt.sign({id: user.id}, 
                config.get('app:tokenSecret'), 
                { expiresInMinutes: config.get('app:sessionExpiryInMins') }
            );
            logger.d('-- Login success: ')
            res.json({token: token})
          } else {
            logger.d('-- Login failed: ' + err)
            res.send(401)
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method to revoke tokens with JWT.

One relatively popular approach is to use [Redis](http://redis.io/) to manage expired tokens.

There's a good guide [here](http://www.kdelemme.com/2014/05/12/use-redis-to-revoke-tokens-generated-from-jsonwebtoken/).